# How can I add release description to a TAG using GITLAB API

Tags: api, rest, gitlab, tags

Using

`GET local/api/v4/projects/project_ID/repository/tags/TAG_NAME/`

I can get info about TAG. How to ask only about RELEASE DESCRIPTION of this TAG?

How to PUT RELEASE DESCRIPTION to a specific TAG, it used to works for me something like that:

```
static async Task<string> add_tag_release_notes2(string repository, int appId, string tag_name, string notes_description) //PUT or POST last TAG notes description 
        {
            string req_path = which_repo(repository)[0] + "projects/" + appId + "/repository/tags/" + tag_name + "/release";
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), req_path)) //PUT won't work as well
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("PRIVATE-TOKEN", which_repo(repository)[1]);
                request.Content = new StringContent(notes_description, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var add_tag_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tag>(content);
                string notes = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                return notes;
            }
```

but now i get response : 404 not found
even

`GET local/api/v4/projects/project_ID/repository/tags/TAG_NAME/release`

won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

They moved release [enter link description here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/)